# Searching equivalent for PHP functions

Tags: c#, function, hex, ascii

I ran in to some problems by converting an Integer to something String formatted. I got these PHP functions which is exactly what I need in C#:

```
function _hex($int)
{
    return (strlen(sprintf("%X", $int)) % 2 == 0) ? sprintf("%X", $int) : sprintf("0%X",     $int);
}
Function hex2str($hexstr)
{
    $hexstr = str_replace(' ', '', $hexstr);
    $hexstr = str_replace('\x', '', $hexstr);
    $retstr = pack('H*', $hexstr);
    return $retstr;
}
```

They get called so:

```
$total_length = hex2str(_hex(strlen($content)));
```

In C# I tried this:

```
String test = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789";
short l = (short)test.Length;
byte[] TotalLength = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(l.ToString());
```

The result of PHPs HexDump is `00 3C` - In C# I get `34 39`

I expect the result as a String in this format:

`\x00\x3c`

Greetings,
Moritz

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example code, the values 34/39 are correctly formatted hex numbers for the output bytes, so I'm not sure how you came up with 00/3C.

However to convert numeric values to hex string in C#, use;

```
string hex = String.Format("{0:X}", number);
```

Or in your more specific case;

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in TotalLength)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("\x{0:X}", b));
}
string hex = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Please check my comment @ Carstens answer.

Comment: If your input value is 60, then this will produce the string '\x3c', however I can't see how you get 60 from your example code.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I require, but I need the \x00\x32 value as a string so I can convert it at the and to send it with a socket.

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns the ASCII values of the value of `l` converted to a string (ASCII 34/39 are 49 - the length of your string). But what you need is the byte[] representation of the length value.

Change the line

```
byte[] TotalLength = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(l.ToString());
```

to

```
byte[] TotalLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(l);
```

Please note that on intel CPUs a value of 15 converts to 0F-00 instead of 00-0F. The high-byte comes first. When you convert your byte array to a string, you must take care of this.

To convert a byte value into a hex string, use

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = TotalLength.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    sb.Append("\\x");
    sb.Append(TotalLength[i].ToString("x2"));
}
string hex = sb.ToString();
```

P.S.: local variables should start with a lower-case character.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, its nearly that what I need. I think the best is to visit this site: http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php and enter `003c` as a Hex value. Deciaml is 60, exactly this is what I needm but reversed. I want to give an int and get the hex value like that above.